# using setfacl to give access to another user without giving access to a group

Tags: linux, backup, group-policy, ext4, acl

I have a user that I use for backup, and I use `setfacl` to give that user access to files.  However, `setfacl` changes the base ACL entry for group and some applications require that the base ACL entry for group be `0` (no read, write, nor execute).  Is there a way I can give the backup user read access without the applications getting uppity?  An example below of how `setfacl` and the base ACL entries interfere:

```
user@host:/tmp$ umask 0077
user@host:/tmp$ touch a
user@host:/tmp$ ls -l a
-rw------- 1 user user 0 2012-02-01 16:28 a
user@host:/tmp$ setfacl -m u:nobody:rX a
user@host:/tmp$ ls -l a
-rw-r-----+ 1 user user 0 2012-02-01 16:28 a
user@host:/tmp$ chmod 600 a
user@host:/tmp$ getfacl a
user:nobody:r--                 #effective:---
```

EDIT: I could use root as my backup user, but I don't think I should.  I'm using rsnapshot (using rsync (using ssh)) to backup to a remote system, and I think I would have to PermitRootLogin to ssh or make my backup user uid 0.  Additionally, I'd like the backup to be automated, which I'm currently doing with ssh keys.  Although I don't mind if the backup system has read access to the backed-up system, I would mind if it had write access.

Comment: Could you run the backup tool as `root` instead?

Answer (score 1):

No. If a POSIX ACL is present, the Unix "group" permissions will be mapped to the ACL `mask::` entry, which sets the maximum allowed permissions for all ACL entries, in order to not break compatibility with ACL-unaware tools. (See [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/352915/5799) for a detailed explanation.)

Comment: Can you do this without ACLs on ext4?  Can you do this without ext4?

Comment: No, and ... depends on the filesystem.

Comment: Can you recommend a [free or open source] file system?